# Single Submission For Multiple Facebook Apps

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

Our company currently uses 3 different Facebook Apps for the production servers; all of them performing exactly the same function.
3 different apps just as load distributors(just to avoid the throttle limits).

Now we want to submit these Apps for review.
Is there any way to get all these apps reviewed in a **single submission** since they perform exactly the same function ???

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First of all: No, you have to go through the review process with every single App.

That being said, using several different Apps just to avoid API limits is not a good idea. I am sure Facebook does not like that. You are actually trying to circumvent something that´s there for a reason. Reduce the number of API calls and always use User Tokens and it should be no problem at all.

You also have to use the Business Mapping API to match users between the Apps. A lot of work to avoid API limits...